# Is Stack Exchange part of the OpenID Foundation?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, openid

As I post this, I don't see the Stack Exchange logo on the OpenID Foundation's [sponsoring members page](http://openid.net/foundation/sponsoring-members/). This means Stack Exchange is not a member of the OpenID Foundation, right?

If so,

- does that mean anything with respect to SE being an OpenID provider?
- Is there any reason SE should be a member of the OpenID Foundation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This means StackExchange is not a member of the OpenID Foundation, right?

Right.

> does that mean anything with respect to SE being an OpenID provider?

No. You don't need to be a member of the OpenID Foundation to be an OpenID provider.

> Is there any reason SE should be a member of the OpenID Foundation?

Not really. I don't see anything in the [membership benefits](http://openid.net/foundation/benefits-members/) that would directly benefit SE's goal of building high quality Q&A sites. If SE wants to help OpenID further its own goals, then of course they could join the foundation, but other than that I don't think there's any reason for membership.

Comment: Maybe worth to mention Stack Exchange donated $1000 to the OpenID foundation back in 2010: http://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/12/stack-overflow-gives-back-2010/